# Missing data in Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I have deployed Cassandra server from google cloud marketplace with the below configurations
Instance _count:7, machine_type:e2-highmem-4, zone: us-east4-a

The configuration details and queries for creation of the keyspace and table are as follows:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE migration
WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};

CREATE TABLE migration.mock_data ( 
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY, 
  first_name text,  
  last_name text, 
  email text, 
  gender text
);

COPY migration.mock_data (id, first_name, last_name, email, gender) 
FROM 'MOCK_DATA.csv'
WITH HEADER = TRUE;
```

And tried loading some test data of 1000 rows for my migration project, but surprisingly I found some data missing from the database.

[Output of the select query is given in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRzzh.png)

Any inputs on this issue will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only explanation I see, is that there are 106 rows with duplicate `id`s.

Comment: As Aaron correctly mentions, duplicate IDs within the source file are the most likely explanation there. You should also avoid using simple strategy and create keyspaces with NetworkTopologyStrategy

Comment: In the source file I have unique GUId's, when fetching the records the output record count is not consistent, its giving different output for each run.